# How do I remove/add line on pattern match using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

What I try to accomplish with 'sed' is to remove a line if the pattern match.
and adding a line if pattern doesn't match.

But how could I make this?
Thanks in advance

Example:
I want this to use this line in Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * script 1 test
```

With a other script I want to remove this line if this pattern is there, and otherwise, if pattern is not matching then add this line.

Comment: Can you show an example input and desired output?

Comment: I've edited the first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v tgt='*/1 * * * * script 1 test' 'index($0,tgt){found=1;next} {print} END{if (!found) print tgt}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/pattern/{h;d};$a\append new line' file
```

Comment: crontab -l | sed /'script\ 2'/d | crontab -

I use this to remove the line, But adding the line if it doesn't exist, is the problem. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @user1621988 what you need to do is make a flag if the line is deleted and use its presence or lack of presence to not add or add an additional line. If the pattern is present a copy is placed in a register called the hold space before it is deleted. this acts as a flag which can be tested. If the flag has not been set when we reach the end of file then the additional line can be added.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to tag your automatically added crontab entries with a comment:

```
* * * * * script 1 test #projectfoo-testjob
```

This allows you to easily remove the job:

```
sed -i.bak '/projectfoo-testjob/d' file
```

or add it:

```
grep -q "projectfoo-testjob" file || \
  echo '*/1 * * * * script 1 test #projectfoo-testjob' >> file
```

By tagging the job like this, you prevent duplicates when the user reformats their crontab e.g. to use tabs instead of spaces, and you prevent deleting similar jobs that the user added for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Only append line if not found in file using grep -qF 'line' file && echo 'line' >> file:

```
grep -qF '*/1 * * * * script 1 test' file || echo '*/1 * * * * script 1 test' >> file
```